# How can i fix this top sticking div at top

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a portfolio website, as you can see my first div (typing about me) is coming below my second div. I want my first div to be visible in full screen in mobile and desktop.

```js
var typed = new Typed('#type-1', {
  strings: [
    'Hey, <br> This is <strong id="ft1">Geekfool</strong>, <br>web developer!'
  ],
  typeSpeed: 100,
  loop: false,
  showCursor: false,
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.main h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: 'Secular One', sans-serif;
}

#ft1 {
  color: #7d5fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #32ff7e;
}

.main h6 {
  animation-name: mini;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes mini {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item-left {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 50%;
}

.flex-item-right {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 50%;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes a one column-layout instead of two-column layout */

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:wght@200&family=Secular+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <!-- Head Section Name, Slogan -->
    <h1 id="type-1"></h1>
    <h6>Frintend Developer / Backend Developer / WordPress</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <!-- Bio Section and Profile Image -->
    <div class="flex-item-left">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-right">
      Two
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Bio Section and Profile Image END -->

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamgeekfool/fp2hv5b0/12/)

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve a and what propblem you are running into a little bit more

Comment: @user18074821 the issue is pretty clear. he want "the first div to be full screen" which means to fill out the entire viewport. currently it is not and the text of the first div overflows the first div into the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Simply give the first div a height of `min-height: 100vh;`. Then remove the absolute positioning and use flexbox to center the text instead. See comments within CSS for full explaination.

```js
var typed = new Typed('#type-1', {
  strings: [
    'Hey, <br> This is <strong id="ft1">Geekfool</strong>, <br>web developer!'
  ],
  typeSpeed: 100,
  loop: false,
  showCursor: false,
});
```

```css
.main {
  min-height: 100vh; /* makes first div as height as the "screen" (viewport) */
  display: flex; /* to align text vertically and horizontally */
  flex-direction: column; /* to have the h6 text below the h1 text (normal block-level-element behavior) */
  justify-content: center; /* centers along main axis (vertically) */
  align-items: center; /* centers along side axis (horizontally */
}


/* orginial css */
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
}
.main {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    margin: 0;
  /* remove
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
     transform: translateY(-50%); */
}
.main h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-family: 'Secular One', sans-serif;
}
#ft1 {
    color: #7d5fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #32ff7e;
}
.main h6 {
    animation-name: mini;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    color: white;
}
@keyframes mini {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    25% { opacity: 0; }
    50% { opacity: 0; }
    75% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item-left {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 50%;
}

.flex-item-right {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 50%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a one column-layout instead of two-column layout */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:wght@200&family=Secular+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <!-- Head Section Name, Slogan -->
    <h1 id="type-1"></h1>
    <h6>Frintend Developer / Backend Developer / WordPress</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <!-- Bio Section and Profile Image -->
    <div class="flex-item-left">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-right">
      Two
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Bio Section and Profile Image END -->

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>
</body>

</html>
```